# What happened to the M2.com standard?

Tags: connector, standard, history, iot, m2

I just discovered some [news articles](https://www.newelectronics.co.uk/electronics-technology/m2-com-internet-of-things-sensor-platform-unveiled/117031/) from 2016 announcing an IoT standard called "M2.com", with quite a few big names supporting it. It was basically meant to be a standard pinout for the M2 connector carrying I2C, SPI, etc.

But it seems to have vanished without as much as a ripple in the water. This is [the last capture of the website](https://web.archive.org/web/20160531081839/http://m2com-standard.org/) before the servers were taken offline in 2017.

Does anyone know how or why this was dropped? SparkFun is now spearheading something called [MicroMod](https://www.sparkfun.com/micromod) that seems to be a very similar idea.

Comment: hmm, the spec pages have vanished  https://www.embedded.com/sensor-systems-in-the-industrial-iot/  maybe the page was hacked ;) https://www.eetimes.com/why-the-iiot-is-so-vulnerable-to-cyberattacks/?page_number=1

Comment: Advantech claims to have practically invented the standard themselves, though your announcement tags on some other names. Just call them and ask them "what's up with that great open standard you were pushing 5 yrs ago?"

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 that is one possibility indeed ;) I found a single product by Advantech called Wise-1520 of which there are still traces on the website, but whose main product page seems to have been similarly expunged.

Comment: @jonk I'll try that! Fingers crossed for an excellent story rather than "new manager cancelled the project".

Comment: @DamienD Looking forward to it! :)